# Mongodb compass hanging in ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongodb-compass

When I open mongodb-compass from my ubuntu desktop, it hangs immediately. I have tried reinstalling and installing numerous times and have also tried with different versions. All of them seem to have the same problem.

Ubuntu -16.04

Comment: Does it hang on start up or does it hang after you enter your connection details in the connect window? Are there are any errors in the View->Toggle Dev Tools->Console menu? Which version of Compass is it?

Comment: It hangs immediately. I cant even fill in the connection details. Compass verion-1.11.2. And the console doesnt seem to show any errors. This problem started appearing after I killed a compass process from the terminal.

Comment: How was it installed? Download and install the .deb? Is there any messages in the sys log?

Answer (score 0):

Same here on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. 
I tried different Community and Stable releases (1.8.0, 1.8.2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2): all of them turn the screen off at Compass launch. 
Anyway Compass seems to be somehow alive: here the list of Compass-related processes returned by `ps|ax grep`  used on a different machine connected through SSH.

```
8763 ?        Sl     0:02 /usr/share/mongodb-compass/MongoDB Compass
8765 ?        S      0:00 /usr/share/mongodb-compass/MongoDB Compass --type=zygote --no-sandbox
8797 ?        Sl     0:11 /usr/share/mongodb-compass/MongoDB Compass --type=renderer --js-flags=--harmony --no-sandbox --primordial-pipe-token=F555D50CC60655E1026A1CB0CF6D0D19 --lang=it --node-integration=true --hidden-page --enable-pinch --num-raster-threads=1 --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,3553;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,3553;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553 --service-request-channel-token=F555D50CC60655E1026A1CB0CF6D0D19 --renderer-client-id=5 --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
```

I installed Compass 1.12.2 on an different PC (more recent and well-equipped), still with Ubuntu 14.04: in that case everything went right.

Could be anything wrong with old hardware settings? Here the current setting:

HP Compaq 6510b
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 64-bit
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7250  @ 2.00GHz
RAM: 3 GB
3 GB free space
VGA: Intel GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller

**UPDATE**

It seems to be a VGA-related issue: I'm playing right now with Compass on a different Ubuntu 14.04 workstation equipped with an Intel Xeon E3-1200 integrated VGA. In addition to the processes I posted in above, I got another one related to gpu, that probably got killed on the older workstation.

```
2244 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/share/mongodb-compass/MongoDB Compass     --type=gpu-process --no-sandbox --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=1,7,23,59,71 --gpu-vendor-id=0x8086 --gpu-device-id=0x0412 --gpu-driver-vendor --gpu-driver-version --gpu-driver-date --service-request-channel-token=80F0952FAB694EC468ADF19899F9E5CD --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
```